# Converts a string into an array of bytes dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am consuming a web service that return an XML of data, how can i convert a string containing lexical representation xsd:hexBinary not base64 format to Uint8List, coming from java i can do this by :

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
....
byte[] decoder = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexStringXls);
```

or

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
int len = s.length();
byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                         + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
}
return data;
}
```

Comment: Can [xml2json](https://pub.dev/packages/xml2json) package help you ?

Comment: Nop, since i have a complicated XML and my solution work already with XML response

Comment: oh ok, there is [convertor class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-convert/Converter-class.html) in dart but you'll have to search more for custom implementation

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```dart
final s = "somestring";
final List<int> bytes = s.codeUnits;
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/String/codeUnits.html

Comment: nop, there is no somestring, the string that i get is encoded

Comment: i might be wrong, but i though `s.codeUnits[i]` may be the dart equivalent of `Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16)` ...

Comment: nvm, i'm wrong, you still have to reimplement Character.digit...